# how to get several commands into one variable for ease of use

Tags: bash, scripting, variable

I am writing a script and I noticed that a certain line of code is constantly being reused.

So I thought why not put it into a variable for ease of use, and when something changes, I only need to change it in one location.

When I do this:

```
scriptpath="echo -e "\n" && curl -s -u lalala:hihihi ftp://ftp.somewhere.com/folder"
```

and then use the variable as following:

```
$SCRIPTPATH/some_script.sh | bash
```

I get the following error message:

> bash: line 2: $'\n': command not found

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just create a function to do the commands, storing commands in variables is generally bad practice.

Comment: the $SCRIPTPATH is part of a larger command, so i dont know how to combine functions and commands in one line together

Comment: or is it possible to call forth a function with a variable?

Comment: something like this

'function scriptpath
{
echo -e "\n" && curl -s -u lalala:hihihi ftp://ftp.somewhere.com/folder/$SCRIPTNAME | bash
}'

but then i need to give the SCRIPTNAME variable a value when calling forth the scriptpath function

Comment: Perhaps you could give a more full picture of what you're actually trying to do, it feels like we might have something of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You can pass arguments to functions, does that solve the problem there?

Comment: Why is it that you need to pass \n to the command line before doing curl?

Comment: "A certain piece of code is constantly being reused" is the _definition_ of when you should consider using a function.

Comment: If that piece of code is repeatedly used within the same program (script), put it in a function. If it's used repeatedly from outside a single program, put it in a script. In any case, your question is unclear, since it doesn't show what you're actually doing (`scriptpath` doesn't look like a path, should it be one? Is there some relation between `scriptpath` and `SCRIPTPATH`?) Please [edit] your question to clarify it (don't just put the clarifications in comments).

Comment: Also, if you're running `curl ... | bash` (repeatedly), you may want to consider if it's a safe and sane thing to blindly run code downloaded from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing a situation in which a function is exactly what you want.

```
do_download () {
    printf '\n'
    curl -s -u lalala:hihihi ftp://ftp.somewhere.com/folder
}
```

You would then use this in your code as

```
do_download
```

If the function needs to take an argument, for example the URL to use,

```
do_download () {
    printf '\n'
    curl -s -u lalala:hihihi "$1"
}
```

Then call it as

```
do_download "ftp://ftp.somewhere.com/folder"
```

Storing commands in variables is *very rarely* something that you'd want to do as quoting and word splitting is difficult to get right.  See e.g. "[How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946)".